# .NET Entityframework Code First one to many delete

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i am trying to build my first EntityFramework Code First Application. Its an WPF Application.
Therefore i implemented a small Test Model. A Club can have many Competitors, and a competitor must have a Club, so from my 
point of view this looks like a standard 1:n relationship. My problem starts when i want delete competitors from a club.
If i delete the whole club all competitors and the club rows are deleted from my database. But when i only want to delete 
a single competitor the framework throws a DBUpdateException:

*A relationship from the 'Club_Competitors' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'Club_Competitors ' must also in the 'Deleted' state.*

Here is my model:

```
[Table("Competitor")]
public class Competitor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Firstname  { get; set; }
    public string Lastname   { get; set; }

    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }

    public Competitor()
    {

    }
}

[Table("Clubs")]
public class Club
{
    public int Id      { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableList<Competitor> Competitors { get; set; }

    public Club()
    {
        Competitors = new ObservableList<Competitor>();
    }
}
```

in the overridden OnModelCreating i added following line of code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().HasMany(c => c.Competitors).WithRequired(c => c.Club);
```

at programstart I load all Entities into my application

```
    dbsCompetitors.Load();
    dbsClubs.Load();
```

and then bind them to datagrids therefore i created a Getter that accesses the Local Part of DbSet

```
    public ObservableCollection<Club> Clubs
    {
        get { return dbsClubs.Local; }
    }
```

my xaml code looks like this

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Name="dgClubs" ItemsSource="{Binding Clubs}"/>
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Name="dgCompetitors" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dgClubs, Path=SelectedItem.Competitors}"/>
```

when the application closes i just call

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Kind Regards Manu

Comment: can you post the code that you are using to delete a competitor?, also your `competitor` class is missing a property of `public int ClubId`.

Comment: @SOfanatic you don't have to specify `ClubId`, it is a good practice however. If you don't do that EF will just create `Club_Id` on its own.

Comment: problem is elsewhere, how you delete it, post more of that

Comment: @Steve thanks for pointing that out, I guess since I always use it I thought it was required.

Comment: i have updated my question, maybe now the mistake i make is clearer?